# How to Add a ListItem?

Tags: list, infopath, caml-query, caml

I am able to add an item to a list using the CAML below. Now I need to modify it to make sure I can add an attachment as well. What is the syntax to add an attachment?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch OnError="Continue">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
       <Field Name='Title'></Field>
       <Field Name="FirstName"></Field>
       <Field Name="LastName"></Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint Object Model may be better suited for this task. Try looking at the code examples from MSDN about how to work with the `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx

Also, here are a few more code examples to check out:

http://nehasinha.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/programmticallyc-adding-deleting-copying-and-downloading-attachments-in-splist/

Comment: hmm. Not sure about using object model. I am trying to follow this article on infopath.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, to attach a file to an item is not possible. You have to get the _ows_ID value when creating the item, then use the AddAttachment method on the ID value of your item.

Please see the similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100157/add-attachment-with-updatelistitems.

Comment: You answers is good as well. Thanks you for the heads up.